# Yii2 - nested resources best practice

Tags: php, yii2, nested-resources

Using Yii2 framework I cannot find any built-in functionality to implement something called `nested resources` in Ruby on Rails (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

For example, an **Article** has many **Comments**. So I want that comments related to an article will be accessed via `/articles/1/comments` URL when `index` action is used; via `/articles/1/comments/create` when `create` action is used and so on...

Do I have to add multiple action-methods to **ArticlesController** called `actionIndexComments(), actionCreateComment()...` ?

Or should I pass an `?article_id=1` parameter via GET and use it for filtering in  **CommentsController** ?

Or should I maybe implement custom `UrlManager` class that can deal with nested routes? (maybe someone has already implemented it?)

What is the best practice for now?

Comment: I think it's best to have multiple actions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do this easily with the UrlManager. It also depends on where you want to put the actual actions. You can put them either in a article controller or comment controller

For example for the comments controller you can define rules like this:

```
'article/<article_id:\d+>/comments/create/' => 'comment/create',
'article/<article_id:\d+>/comments/' => 'comment/index',
```

In both cases you can access the article_id (in GET) in the create or index actions. You can do exactly the same thing if you want to put the actions in the article.

Comment: can you please help me, im new in yii, where should i actually define these rules? i have `teams` and `playes` and i want my url to be like `teams/1/player/create` where 1 is `team_id`

Answer (score 4):

For more universe:

```
'GET,HEAD v1/articles/<id:\d+>/comments' =>
    'v1/articles/comment/index',
'GET,HEAD v1/<article/<id:\d+>/comments/<id:\d+>' =>
    'v1/articles/comment/view',
'POST v1/articles/<id:\d+>/comments' =>
    'v1/articles/comment/create',
'PUT,PATCH v1/article/<id:\d+>/comments' =>
    'v1/articles/comment/update',
'DELETE v1/article/<id:\d+>/comments' =>
    'v1/articles/comment/delete',
```

Answer (score 1):

In case it is related to the built-in REST Api and you are using [yii\rest\UrlRule](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-urlrule.html) instead of [yii\web\UrlRule](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlrule.html) then its [$prefix](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-urlrule.html#$prefix-detail) property may help achieving that by doing:

```
'rules' => [
    [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
        'controller' => ['players' => 'v1/player', 'trophies' => 'v1/trophy'],
        'prefix' => 'teams/<team_id:\d+>',
    ],
],
```

Which will generate the required rules for the following endpoints:

```
/teams/1/players
/teams/1/players/2
/teams/1/trophies
/teams/1/trophies/4
```

There is also this [extension](https://github.com/tunecino/yii2-nested-rest) built on top of that principle and also provides related helper actions.

Comment: Finally solution that works! The missing important trick was: 'controller' => ['players' => 'v1/player', 'trophies' => 'v1/trophy'].